# Openoffice crash on addon load in Linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, javafx, openoffice.org

OpenOffice crashes when i'm trying to launch an addon in linux, but it fine in windows. Addon is written in javafx. The crash happens occasionally not always and it happens only at the launch, if program loads then it works fine.

logs:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc
Fatal exception: Signal 6
Stack:
/opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x37a9a)[0x7f3b84896a9a]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x37bcc)[0x7f3b84896bcc]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x37c69)[0x7f3b84896c69]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x33b20)[0x7f3b834e4b20]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f3b834e4a97]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f3b834e5e6a]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0xfd)[0x7f3b83dcff5d]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ee56)[0x7f3b83dcde56]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5de59)[0x7f3b83dcce59]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(__gxx_personality_v0+0x10a)[0x7f3b83dcd65a]
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1(+0xfff3)[0x7f3b83863ff3]
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1(_Unwind_Resume+0x57)[0x7f3b83864517]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libvcl.so(+0x17fffe)[0x7f3b7fb42ffe]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x36862)[0x7f3b84895862]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3(+0x37c4a)[0x7f3b84896c4a]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x33b20)[0x7f3b834e4b20]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f3b834e4a97]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f3b834e5e6a]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x16d)[0x7f3b83dcffcd]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ee56)[0x7f3b83dcde56]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5eea1)[0x7f3b83dcdea1]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5f0b8)[0x7f3b83dce0b8]
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice.bin(__gxx_personality_v0+0x28c)[0x40108c]
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice.bin(_Znwm+0x17)[0x401137]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libvclplug_gtk.so(+0x260f5)[0x7f3b77fa40f5]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libvclplug_gtk.so(+0x2610a)[0x7f3b77fa410a]
/opt/openoffice4/program/libvclplug_gtk.so(+0x25ba9)[0x7f3b77fa3ba9]
/usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x58173)[0x7f3b76613173]
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_check+0x181)[0x7f3b76efc671]
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49c33)[0x7f3b76efcc33]
/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0xc2)[0x7f3b76efd022]
/usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xb7)[0x7f3b7699f3f7]
/opt/java/jre/lib/amd64/libglass.so(Java_com_sun_glass_ui_gtk_GtkApplication__1runLoop+0x7d)[0x7f3b135c8bed]
[0x7f3b49018c39]
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice: line 121: 18278 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$sd_prog/$sd_binary" "$@"
```

Any idea on what causes the crash?

fragment of code where GUI init happens:

```
public class AboutDialog {

    private final static Paint DIALOG_COLOR = Color.BEIGE;
    private static JFrame dialog = new JFrame();
    private String windowName = "";

    public AboutDialog(String windowName) {
        this.windowName = windowName;
        showDialog();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if(OOUtil.isLinux()){
            initGUI();
        }else
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initGUI();
            }
        });

    }

    public void initGUI() {
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
        dialog.setIconImage(icon);

        position(dialog);

        dialog.setTitle(windowName);
        dialog.setResizable(false);

        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        dialog.setContentPane(fxPanel);

        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scene scene = new Scene(new AboutController(AboutDialog.this), 300, 250);
                fxPanel.setScene(scene);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JFrame getDialog() {
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) is thrown when `new` (or `new[]`) can't allocate enough memory. Is your plugin (it *is* your plugin?) creating lot of big objects?

Comment: plugin just loads simple javafx window which connects to another application.  (Yes my companies addon)

Comment: Possibly provide the code that gets called on start-up if possible.

Comment: Tried to debug from code, crash heppens on the line where javafx thread is launching:  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            ...
           }
     });

Comment: From the looks of it, it's an OpenOffice bug, you might report it.